Error in download data from yahoo in r using tq_get function
i want to download the stock data. When i use the tq_get function, it shows that Caused by warning:
! x = 'RCL', get = 'stock.prices': Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "RCL", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, : Unable to import “RCL”.
HTTP error 403.

So how can i download the stock data, please help.

I tried many ways but it still can not download the stock

It seems you're in Mainland China. If you go to Yahoo Finance's website, you'll see their announcement that they stopped their service in Mainland China several years ago. So you'll need a VPN to get any stock data from Yahoo Finance. Don't forget to set the VPN mode as full-mask.
